# Efficient way to create a sorted, queue whose Iterator repeats back to the beginning in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, linked-list, iteration

I'm looking for an implementation or method of creating a mutable (with frequent updates), sorted, queue or list, that repeats in iteration. An example would be something [1, 3, 4, 9] where next() cycles through the elements, and returns back to 1 after 9. Elements are removed and added frequently, and need to be correctly sorted.

My initial plan for this was to use a LinkedList or PriorityQueue, but problems grew. I need the Queue to be sorted (preferably on updation rather than on iteration), hence using PriorityQueue, but I also need the queue to repeat when iterating (done manually, not with a loop). I considered making a class that held a Comparator and wrapped the Iterator, which looked a bit like this

```java
public class SortedRepeatingQueue<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;
    private Iterator<T> iterator = iterator();

    public SortedRepeatingQueue(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public T next() {
        Collections.sort(this, comparator);
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator = iterator();
        }
        return iterator.next();
    }
}
```

However, this would create problems if an entry was removed or added during iteration, as the cached Iterator wouldn't be updated, and updating it would require a hefty bit of work making sure we continue at the same index. For example, if we were iterating over [1,2,3,5], were at 3 and then inserted 4, updating the iterator to make sure next() returned 4 instead of 5 would be tricky.
Another option was a simple extension of List where next() takes the first element, returns it and then moves it to the back (eg [1,3,4,5].next() returns 1 and creates [3,4,5,1]). However, this would be overridden by any sorting done on the list.
I also considered a completely custom implementation, but I don't really trust myself to create a safe, fully working implementation of this, and it would be quite time consuming.

I'm looking for any method of handling this that is fast (although speed is not a major priority as n should never really be bigger than 20-30), because I'm completely stumped.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is supposed to be a concurrent queue? If so, you do need a completely custom implementation, JDK doesn't have anything that would tick all these boxes.

Comment: Concurrency isn't necessary, this is for an Android app which AFAIK will be running in one thread. I think you're right about needing a custom implementation - I had the idea of overriding iterator() that purely uses indexes but PriorityQueue doesn't support indexed based lookup :(
Custom implementation it is then, unless anyone else has any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I bit the bullet and wrote my own implementation

```java
/**
 * Implementation of {@link java.util.Queue} that represents a continuous queue of ordered data.
 * Elements are automatically sorted when added, by a given {@link Comparator}
 * This class is useful for something like a turn based game, in which a group of users take turns to perform
 * an action, and then repeat back to the first user.
 * Because of this, direct iteration or looping over <strong>WILL REPEAT INDEFINITELY</strong>, causing an
 * infinite loop.
 * A more suited example would be something like:
 * <p>
 * var currentPlayingUser;
 * while(game in progress){
 * //wait for the user to take their turn
 * currentPlayingUser = queue.poll();
 * }
 *
 * @param <T> The type of element in the queue
 * @author Alexander Wood http://bristermitten.me
 */
public class SortedRepeatingQueue<T> extends AbstractQueue<T> {

    /**
     * Internal list for this implementation.
     * This list is guaranteed to be sorted at all times
     */
    private final List<T> backingList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Comparator<T> comparator;
    private Itr iterator = iterator();

    public SortedRepeatingQueue(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    /**
     * Return, but do not remove the head element.
     * Due to the cyclic nature, removing the head element would not match the intended functionality.
     * However, this will cycle through the elements. That is, given a SortedRepeatingQueue [1,2,3]
     * poll will return 1, then 2, then 3, then 1, etc
     * <p>
     * This is functionally equivalent to the head element being moved to the tail rather than removed, although
     * is not what happens.
     *
     * @return The "head" element of this SortedRepeatingQueue
     */
    @Override
    public T poll() {
        return iterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        return iterator.nextWithoutCycle();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(T t) {
        return add(t);
    }

    public boolean add(T e) {
        backingList.add(e);
        backingList.sort(comparator);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean b = backingList.addAll(c);
        backingList.sort(comparator);
        return b;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return backingList.remove(o);
    }

    public Itr iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }

    public int size() {
        return backingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SortedRepeatingQueue{" +
                "backingList=" + backingList +
                '}';
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<T> {
        private int cursor = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return true;
        }

        public T next() {
            if (cursor == backingList.size()) {
                cursor = 0;
            }
            return backingList.get(cursor++);
        }

        public T nextWithoutCycle() {
            if (cursor == backingList.size()) {
                cursor = 0;
            }
            return backingList.get(cursor);
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (cursor == backingList.size()) {
                cursor = 0;
            }
            backingList.remove(cursor);
        }
    }
}
```

It uses a cursor-based iterator and wraps a sorted ArrayList to achieve exactly the functionality needed. Elements can be inserted or removed and the iterator will update accordingly. Direct iteration in a loop will cause an infinite loop, but that was not the intended purpose. A brief example use case is in the Javadocs, and most methods should have obvious or inherited functionality, and any that don't are documented.

Hopefully this helps someone else if they have my very specific issue